# Perl DBIx::Class - Default Values when using new()?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

When using the new() method on a DBIx::Class ResultSource to create a (potentially temporary) variable, it doesn't seem to populate attributes with the default values specified in the DBIC schema (which we have specified for creating tables from that schema).

Currently, we are creating one default value for one such class (the first case where this was a problem) with

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = $class->next::method(@_);
  $self->queue('DEFAULT_QUEUE_VAL') unless $self->queue();
  return $self;
}
```

in that class (i.e., the attribute queue=>DEFAULT_QUEUE_VAL).  However, longer term, we have several DBIC classes that have various default values, and we'd like to avoid replicating the above logic for all the various cases.

Are there any CPAN modules/plugins available to do this?  We didn't see any in our (admittedly cursory) search of CPAN.

Edit: fixed some garbage in the code sample; turns out I cp'd from out-of-date code.

Comment: It's worth noting that any technique of this sort will break if your default isn't a simple value (e.g. it's an SQL function call). If possible it's recommended that you just insert the row into the database (possibly inside a transaction for safety) and query back the column value. Only do what you're asking if that technique doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no DBIC component for this, you can do it with a small mod to your existing code though:

```
sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = $class->next::method(@_);
  foreach my $col ($self->result_source->columns) {
    my $default = $self->result_source->column_info($col)->{default_value};
    $self->$col($default) if($default && !defined $self->$col());
  return $self;
}
```

As it's this straight forward, there's not much point for a component.

Comment: Looks pretty good; we are in fact looking to make such either a component or an actual change to the framework.  Are you interested in credit on that?

Comment: I'd suggest a component. And yes ;) (CPAN: JROBINSON)

Comment: rock on; there are some, uh, weird issues with us making contributions directly, so perhaps we'll chat about doing it through you.

Answer (score 0):

isn't your code calling queue() as a class method instead of an object method? did you mean

```
$new->queue('DEFAULT_QUEUE_VAL') unless $new->queue();
```

?

edit - sorry, just re-read the question, and presume that's just a typo

a thought - if the default value is in the SQL schema, then do you need to set it in the object as well? if you pass through NULL (undef) you'll get the default value in the table, and to reflect that in the object set the subclassed new() method to re-read the db row (->discard_changes() will do it i think?)

Comment: Unfortunately, the site behavior depends on the default value; hence it is needed before anything is ever written to the table.  That is, we're making a potential record, which a user then manipulates and then either discards or submits-which turns it into an actual record in the table.

Comment: sorry, missed the 'temporary variable' bit - was answering this too early in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to have a 'saved' field in the database which you mark when you have saved it. you can use views to distinguish between saved objects and new ones.

This approach will be slower but allow you to pick up DATETIME or other DB specific defaults that the answer above may have problems with.